# How do I fire the enter keypress event of <input type="text"> programmatically in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I have this `<input type="text">` element whose <kbd>enter</kbd> `keypress` event I want to fire via the ng-click of another button.

i.e.,

Lets say :

```
<button ng-click="clickEvent()"></button>
<input type="text" id="textbox"></input>
```

Plnkr is here : http://plnkr.co/edit/tEVoHAAcyqQzWpc9iYpo?p=preview

Please help!

Comment: could you elaborate! Why do you want to rise other buttons event? just call the event  handler of that button  instead.

Comment: I need to press enter inside a "text" field X on clicking a button Y.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating angular directive. JSFiddle for reference - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n3105Lzv/)
See the console after click on `Click Me !` button. Hope this will help!

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <h1>Hello JSFiddle!</h1>
  <button id="btnClick" ng-click="clicked()" capture-keypress>Click Me !</button>
  <input ng-keydown="keypress($event)" id="txtInput">
</body>


app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.keypress = function($event) {
    console.log('Key Event Fired');
  };
});

app.directive('captureKeypress', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.clicked = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          element.siblings('#txtInput').trigger('keydown');
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```